# Unable to get ng-switch working

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and i'm trying to use ng-switch to dynamically load templates using include in bootstrap modal but click doesn't seem to work. What am i doing wrong here ?

HTML

ModalContent.html

```
<div ng-controller="Nav" class="modal-body">
  <div class="left-nav" ng-include="'LeftNav.html'"></div>
  <div class="right-nav" ng-include="'RightNav.html'"></div>
</div>
```

LeftNav.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <a href="#" ng-click="page='item'">{{ item }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

RightNav.html

```
<div ng-switch on="page">
    <div ng-switch-when="Item1">
        <div ng-include="'Item1.html'"></div>
    </div>  
    <div ng-switch-when="item2">
        <div ng-include="'Item2.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="item3">
        <div ng-include="'Item3.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
       <h1>Default</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Nav', function($scope) {
     $scope.items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];      
})
```

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/D1tMRpxVzn51g18Adnp8?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of problems.

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/CZPvD373HbCC2Ism0xlA?p=preview

Comments inline:

**Controller**

```js
app.controller('Nav', function($scope) {
     $scope.items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];  
     $scope.page = $scope.items[0];
     $scope.selectItem = function (item) {
         $scope.page = item;
     }

})
```

**LeftNav template**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <!-- calling `selectItem` on the controller to set the `page`
           otherwise `page` will be set on the current `ng-include` scope 
           and will be unavailable elsewhere -->
      <a href="#" ng-click="selectItem(item)">{{ item }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**RightNav template**

```
<!-- 'page' is now from the 'Nav' controller's $scope -->
<div ng-switch on="page">
    <div ng-switch-when="Item1">
        <div ng-include="'Item1.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- String matches are case sensitive -->  
    <div ng-switch-when="Item2">
        <div ng-include="'Item2.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- String matches are case sensitive -->
    <div ng-switch-when="Item3">
        <div ng-include="'Item3.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
       <h1>Default</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```